# Dynamic array filter function with variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'm a JS noob and have been stuck on a dynamic filter problem. I have a an array of objects that's being built in the background. Each object has several '**fields**', one of which is '**time**'.

I want to be able to filter the array to keep all objects such that
`obj.field.time > t - dt/2` and `obj.field.time < t + dt/2`.

From other forums I know how to do that for constants (see below simplified extract of my code)

```
filtered_array = array.filter(obj => obj.field.time >= t - dt/2 && obj.field.time <= t + dt/2)
```

But how do I do that if **t** and **dt** can vary? Also, not sure if this has an impact but my "array" is also gradually evolving(every timestep **dt** a few lines are added to it)

Many thanks in advance!

[Edit - added code for clarification]

```
t = 0;
dt = 0.2;
play = false; // a button on the interface can toggle the play boolean

setInterval(playTime, dt * 1000);

function playTime() {
    if (play) {
        t = t + dt;
        filtered_array = vdData_flat.filter(obj => obj.fields.time >= t - dt / 2 && obj.fields.time <= t + dt / 2)

        console.log('extract: ', filtered_array);
    }
}
```

and then here's the bit where vdData_flat is updated:

```
ticksSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
    data = JSON.parse(event.data);
    [...other stuff...]
    vdData.push(data);
    vdData_flat = flatten(vdData);
}
```

with:

```
    // Function for flattening vdData
function flatten(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function (flat, toFlatten) {
        return flat.concat(Array.isArray(toFlatten) ? flatten(toFlatten) : toFlatten);
    }, []);
}
```

Comment: `==>` what? is not valid syntax, you probably meant `=>`

Comment: From where t and dt coming?

Comment: Does `t` and `dt` vary for each element? How do they change? If they are just variables in the scope and are not affected by the current item being checked, then you just use them.

Comment: @Berto99 yep sorry that was a typo (amended)

Comment: @crashmstr added above some context on how they change. In theory they are not affected by vdData_flat, but the code above does not seem to work

Comment: Hi all. I'm still stuck on this. Does any one have a potential solution? Thanks!